# WPF Touch/Panning Scroll Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf

For `C#` `WPF`, there is a event handler `MouseWheel` for scrolling using mouse wheel. Is there any similar event handler for scrolling using touch/panning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `ScrollViewer` and you have touch hardware (which causes manipulation events to occur), then you can use the `PanningMode` property.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode(v=vs.110).aspx

If you don't have touch hardware, and you want the mouse to be used for panning, then you can add some additional behaviour to a `ScrollViewer` to support that.

- [Can i scroll an ItemsControl by dragging row items instead of scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576633/can-i-scroll-an-itemscontrol-by-dragging-row-items-instead-of-scrollbar/43577390#43577390)

If you want a normal mouse to be able to generate cause "manipulation" events to occur (i.e. simulate a touch device)....then you can use the MultiTouch SDK to provide a new device that will map mouse events to touch ones - something you don't normally get.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansont/2010/01/30/custom-touch-devices/
- [How do I Emulate touch events without using touch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489004/how-do-i-emulate-touch-events-without-using-touch-screen)
- [WPF: Is there a possibility to "route" ordinary mouse events to touch events in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352529/wpf-is-there-a-possibility-to-route-ordinary-mouse-events-to-touch-events-in)

If you have want to handle manipulation events (via real touch hardware, or the simulated one via MultiTouch SDK), and have `PanningMode` work at the same time on the `ScrollViewer`...use this.

- [Manipulation event and panning mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953995/manipulation-event-and-panning-mode)